# Best practices of dealing with very large arrays? DB?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, large-data

In another question, I stated that I was running a php script that grabbed 150 rows of data from a mysql database, then did some calculations on that data, which it put into an array (120 elements with an array of 30 for each, or roughly 3600 elements total). The "results" array is needed, because I create a graph with the data. This script works fine.

I wanted to expand my script to a more dense dataset (which would provide better results). The dataset is 1700 rows, which would end up with a "results" array of 1340 elements with an array of 360 for each, or roughly 482,400 elements total.  Problem is, I've tried this and came up with some heinous memory errors.

As described to me in the previous question I posted, the size of that results array is probably overwhelming the server memory

> In you second larger sample it will be array(1700,1699). At 144 bytes per element     thats 415,915,200 bytes, thats slightly over 406Meg + remaining bucket space, just to hold the results of your calculations.

I am not familiar with the typical ways to deal with this issue.  I was considering for the larger set of data, serializing and base64_encode'ing each of the 1340 result array elements, as it runs (or every 10 or 20. 1340 db calls might be too much), and uploading to a SQL server, and unsetting the results array as to free up memory.  I could then make my report and my graph by querying the DB for the specific information, rather than having it ALL in a huge array.

Any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use Hadoop map-reduce and/or other such technologies when dealing with large sets of data. And most of the processing you want to do on the data must be a batch process. The results must be put somewhere else- another database. You will only need to query that database and your application will become much faster and you will not run into memory problems.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and fastest way is probably to continue to use your in memory array solution and figure out how to solve the memory issues.  What are the memory errors you have been encountering?

If you have over 1GB of RAM that should be enough to generate your graph. With 1GB of RAM you can set memory_limit PHP configuration option to 750MB. You could only generate it with one process at a time so you would need to generate it and use some method to cache the results.

If you dont have enough RAM on your current system. I suggest trying Amazon EC2 you can get a 16GB machine for about 7 cents an hour on the spot market which you could just stop and start whenever you needed to generate the graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more specifics on your use case?  How many distinct graphs do you need to service?  How frequently will the underlying data change?  How many concurrent users do you need to serve?  Are you actually trying to plot 2 million elements on a single chart?

In the absence of specifics, I would note/recommended some combination of the following:

1. Build your graphs offline and cache them
2. Use a web-based solution to offload all querying and chart generation (google charts + google fusion table)
3. Use a backend process to do the analysis and generate the graphs, only expose the end result to the client.  Check out R and http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/

Comment: The smaller use-case (150 cycles) plots 3300 points, as described. The larger one *would* be 400k points.  I've certainly considered the back-end process route. I use dygraphs for my graphing.